# Expectation over inequalities

Tags: probability

Suppose $X\in \mathbb R^n$ is a random vector and two positive real valued functions $g(x)>f(x)>0$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Then can we say that the expectations follow  $$Eg(X)>Ef(X)?$$

Comment: Okay, @Henry, I'm posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions $g,f$ are such that $g(X),f(X)$ become random variables and if $Eg(X),Ef(X)$ exist, then, just take $h(x)=g(x)−f(x)>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $h(X)$ is a r.v. and $Eh(X)$ exists and is $>0$.